# Pick largest M values in array and set the rest to zero without changing the index

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to pick the m largest values in an array and set everything else to zero.
I know one route is to order the array in descending order and set everything else to zero but this changes the index of the max values and that's not what I want.

Is there a way to do this without the loop? I'm looking at arrays that have 600,000+ elements so I think a for loop would take too long.

Essentially what i want is:

```
X = [1 4 6 90 10 32 433 69]
M = 4

newX = [0 0 0 90 0 32 433 69]
```

but on a much larger size...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function can also return the original indices of the sorted values. Using this we can find the indices of the values that are *not* in the top 4 and set them to zero:

```
X = [1 4 6 90 10 32 433 69]
M = 4

[~, inds] = sort(X, 'descend');
Y = X;
Y(inds(M+1:end)) = 0;
```

Result:

```
Y =    
     0     0     0    90     0    32   433    69
```

Note that this code will work even if `numel(X) <= 4`. The list indexing `Y` will simply be empty in this case and no elements will be set to 0.

Comment: I tried a few tricks removing lower values hoping to find something faster than sort, but I came up short.  Simple and solid.

Comment: @Matt I'm a bit worried about the time taken for `sort` on 600,000 elements. It might actually turn out faster to do `max` 4 times and set the correct elements in a preallocated array.

Comment: I tried something like that for a 600,000 element array of random integers the speed difference was not much (high performance applications aside).  In the end 3 lines of code is much simpler than what I was making.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I just tried 600,000 elements and it took less than a tenth of a second. The `max` method was an order of magnitude faster, but as you say, it's not worth the complexity and it required changing `X`.